# Encryption or encoding filename along data with gpg

Tags: filenames, gpg

**What is the most common practice to gpg encrypt the filename gpg along the data?**

Encrypting the filename with the command

```
$ echo <filename> | gpg -e --trustmodel always
```

leads to a very long encrypted filename (hundreds of symbols for a simple english word as filename).

I know that `encfs` is using a "nameio/block" encoding. Can I use the same for my gpg encrypted filename?

---

PS: `ecryptfs` would do this but I don't want a *OTFE* (On The Fly Encryption).

Answer (score 1):

Use **tar** or **zip** to put the file in an archive. Give the archive a neutral name, such as `archive-2016-12-05-A.zip`. Use **gpg** to encrypt the archive. And since you seem concerned about file names: good security practices in organizations where those things are practiced say that sensitive files should have names which give no hint to their contents; usually serial names such as DEI-17-AC-20161205-33, and sometimes (mostly for case folders) code names generated randomly from a list of words.